# Какой метод жизненного цикла активити вызывается, когда приложение свернуто?

Tags: java, android, activity-life-cycle

Есть приложение, которое в жизненном цикле на фазах перестает посылать данные. Думаю, это связано с жизненным циклом. Меня интересует, когда приложение свернуто и когда экран поставлен на блокировку, какой метод вызывается. Спасибо.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обоих случаях вызовутся сначала onPause, потом onStop

Comment: и тиоритические если я изменю методы on pause и on stop на подсоеденение и получение данных то все будет работать и в свернутом состоянии?

Comment: Да, да, да, да, да

Comment: @elik Нет, не будет работать корректно, т.к. метод `onStop` может не вызваться вовсе.

Comment: Почему он может не вызваться?

Comment: @P.Ilyin потому, что процесс уже будет убит системой, к примеру, потому, что нужно освободить ресурсы для другой деятельности. Обратите внимание на картику жизненного цикла, которая есть в ответе Valery Ponomarenko. Если вы не учитываете этот факт в своих приложениях, то утечка памяти гарантирована.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, вероятность того, что нехватка памяти случиться в течение наносекунд, проходящими между onPause и onStop (если говорить о тех двух ситуациях, что вы приводите в вопросе) настолько фантомна, что едва ли  такая ситуация когда-либо возникала

Comment: @P.Ilyin при разработке приложений нельзя уповать на "вдруг не случится", и я в комментарии не указал, что не будет работать совсем, я указал, что будет работать некорректно. Остальное - дело выбора разработчика. А завершение активити системой для высвобождения ресурсов (нехватка памяти или что-то еще) - отнюдь не редкое явление.

Answer (score 1):

Когда приложение свернуто или экран заблокирован, то понятно, что активность в данный момент не видна. И если посмотреть на схему, то там ясно написано "The activity is no longer visible" -> onStop(), следовательно, будет вызван метод onStop() (и, конечно, все предыдущие методы).

[image: Жизненный цикл активности]

Comment: для полноценного ответа (а не просто картинки) было бы неплохо полностью ответит на вопрос _"когда приложение свернуто и когда экран поставлен на блокировку, какой метод вызывается"_

Comment: @Denis схема отвечает на заданный вопрос.
Когда приложение свернуто или экран заблокирован, то понятно, что активность в данный момент не видна. И если посмотреть на схему, то там ясно написано "The activity is no longer visible" -> onStop(), следовательно, будет вызван метод onStop().

Comment: Для наглядности я бы пояснил именно в теле ответа, чтобы ваш ответ имел большую ценность)

Comment: @Denis учту ваше замечание! :)

Answer (score 1):

По поводу жизненного цикла `Activity` - нужно понимать следующее:

активити может быть уничтожена системой в любой момент после `onPause` и, при этом, система не гарантирует вызов методов жизненного цикла, которые следуют за `onPause`.

Исходя из этого нужно строить план работы с жизненным циклом при уходе активити на задний план.